# Maximizing a two-dimensional continuous function with regard to on variable - Resulting function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is the following statement correct?

> Given a continuous function $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+_0$ and $g(x)$ such that
>   $f(x,g(x))\geq f(x,z)$ for all $z\geq 0$,
>   then $f(x,g(x))$ is continuous.

I hope you can understand the statement.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For instance, pick a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $1$ from below, let $0<\epsilon_n<1-x_n$, and let $f$ be a function which is $0$ except on the rectangles $[x_n-\epsilon_n,x_n+\epsilon_n]\times[n,n+1]$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and on those rectangles it interpolates linearly between the boundary values of $0$ and the value of $1$ at $(x_n,n+1/2)$.  Then $f(x_n,g(x_n))$ would be $1$ for each $n$, but $f(1,y)=0$ for all $y$ and in particular $f(1,g(1))=0$.

Comment: I think after several minutes of pondering I got your proof :-D Thank you very much. Would this be any different if we additionally knew that g(x) is continuous, too?

Comment: If $g$ is continuous then obviously $f(x,g(x))$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions.